# Viewing test failed results bamboo 4.4.4

Tags: testing, junit, bamboo

I have problem in Bamboo 4.4.4:
I've created plan which start some tests and then it generate TestReport.xml.[TestReport](https://answers.atlassian.com/upfiles/TestReport.txt)

I try to parse it with JUnit Parser, but in Test Results Bamboo show only successfull tests and not even one failed.
Any suggestions?
P.S. I atached generated my TestReport.xml and xml-file, that created Bamboo after parse.[buildresults19.txt](https://answers.atlassian.com/upfiles/buildresults19.txt)

Comment: Image:
Result page(test tab) - https://answers.atlassian.com/upfiles/ScreenShot_11_1.jpg
bamboo log on tests - https://answers.atlassian.com/upfiles/ScreenShot_13.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If your having issues with getting the tests to report correctly please contact Atlassian Support - they can help you sort it out quicker than Stack Overflow!

Thanks
James Dumay
Bamboo Product Manager

Comment: Thanks James!
I resolved problem. I have problem with my framework that generated xml not in the same format, which works with Bamboo 2.4.0, but not with Bamboo 4.4.4.